# Error creating new Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse Kepler. I recently deleted my JRE 7 folder and I'm now using the JDK 8. When I create a new project I get a caution sign with something related to compliance level:

[image]

What do I need to do to encounter the problem?

Comment: did you change the variable environement I mean did you change your path to jdk 8

Comment: I changed the jre path to C:/ProgramFiles/java/jdk1.8_60. Still the problem persists. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Change the project's language level to Java 8 as well. Eclipse cannot guarantee that it is really compliant with Java 7 (without a JDK7).

Answer (score 3):

Kepler doesn't have `1.8` compliance support, so you have to update to a newer version of Eclipse (like Juno).

When you do, you have to make sure that you have properly pointed the JDK installation directory in Eclipse. You can navigate to `Window` → `Preferences` → `Java` → `Installed JREs`, add the JDK8 environment (and select it as default, as you don't have any other, since you have deleted 1.7 one).

[image: Installed JREs]

Then, when you navigate to `Window` → `Preferences` → `Java` → `Compiler`, you should be able to select `1.8` as "Compliance level", as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I did the first step but in the second step I don't see a compliance level of 1.8

Comment: Kepler does not have the 1.8 compliance level, a later version of Eclipse is required for Java 8 support.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Kepler does not support Java 8. You need to move to the current release of Eclipse (Eclipse Mars) for full Java 8 support.

Comment: Are there any plugins or features to add 1.8 compliance level to Eclipse Kepler

Comment: Mars!  Does this signify a major milestone or did they just run out of moons?

Comment: There is a patch to add 1.8 support to Kepler but support in the later releases of Eclipse is better.

Comment: @Thilo Just a normal once a year release, the Eclipse developer community votes for the name.